# How to make an absolute positioned element end just before the other element while changing the width of the screen?

Tags: css, flexbox, position, styling, shrink

Let's assume we have a 'parent' block which consists of plenty of element including a button. By pressing this button the user should see a 'slide' element that will cover the parent block  not the full width but only till the button inself(blocks 1 and 2 as you will see on the pen). So the slide should forever ends just before the button. Even when the width of the screen is changed. How could it  be implemented?

[See on Code Pen](https://codepen.io/JulieJones/pen/xxOwZbR)

```
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='first'>1</div>
 <div class='second'>2</div>
 <div class='btn'>Button</div>
 <div class='third'>3</div>

   <div class='slide'>
       Hello 
   </div>
</div>

 .parent {
    display: flex; 
}

 .first, .second, .third {
    padding: 30px;
}

 .first {
   background-color: salmon;
   flex-basis: 120px;
}

 .second {
   background-color: yellow;
   flex-grow: 1
}

.third {
   background-color: #56D7F7;
   flex-grow: 1
}

.btn {
   background-color: red;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0
}
```

Comment: As you want that your div cover 2 others div and one of it having a dynamic width with flex, I would recommend solution with JS. Will it be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a bit of Javascript applying CSS styles. To open the slide, you scale it up by a calculated amount; to close, you just scale it back to its original size.

You might not want to scale the slide element since if there's any content in it, that will appear skewed a bit, but there's not too much work to change this solution to use translations instead.

I don't think there's a pure CSS solution since you have to calculate the position of the button, but of course I could be wrong!

```js
let open = false;

slide.style.setProperty('transform-origin', 'left top');
slide.style.setProperty('transition', 'linear .4s all');

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
  if (open) {
    slide.style.setProperty('transform', `scaleX(1)`);
    open = false;

  } else {
    const first = slide.offsetWidth;
    const last = button.offsetLeft;
    const scale = last / first;
    
    slide.style.setProperty('transform', `scaleX(${scale})`);

    open = true;
  }
})
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.first,
.second,
.third {
  padding: 30px;
}

.first {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex-basis: 120px;
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1
}

.third {
  background-color: #56D7F7;
  flex-grow: 1
}

.btn {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='first'>1</div>
  <div class='second'>2</div>
  <div id="button" class='btn'>Button</div>
  <div class='third'>3</div>

  <div id="slide" class='slide'>
    <div class='hello'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```